# Windows Mobile Emulator connection timeout accessing local web service

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, windows-mobile, device-emulation

I have a Windows Mobile 6 application that is trying to make a web service call to a service hosted on my local machine so I can debug the logon process with VS2008 connecting to both the emulated device and web service.

I have configured the device emulator to connect to the internet and confirmed this by doing a Bing search from IE on the device. I have checked the web service is running and working using the local test form on the machine and having installed [vxUtil](http://www.cam.com/vxutil_pers.html) to the emulated device and checked that I can ping my machine and make a GET request to my web service URL `http://MyMachineName>/Service/MyService.asmx`, both are successful.

The application checks for network connectivity by checking for a web request response from www.google.com and this is successful but when I try and call the login method for the web service I'm getting a .Net SocketException 10060 - *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
failed because connected host has failed to respond*.

*Note: this network connectivity check will be replaced along the lines of this article: [Establish Network Connectivity with the Windows Mobile Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx)*

I have attached an instance of VS2008 to my locally running web service and don't see the request come in from calling the logon method on the emulated device. I assume something is stopping the connection reaching my local machine from the emulator, how else can I find out what is preventing the connection being made?

Comment: It works fine connecting to an instance of the web service not hosted locally, correctly resolving the machine name, so I'm remote debugging that instead. I tried using IE on the device to access the web service on my machine and that doesn't work with IP or machine name but works fine to the remote host. Will need to learn more about the virtual networking.

Comment: Having my virtual network card on the mobile device talk to my real network card seems a step too far. Considering looking into the Loopback Adaptor which sounds like making this possible.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason this would happen is that the DNS lookup for your PC is not working for the WinMo device emulator.  Meaning that when it attempts to resolve "MyMachineName" it's eitehr getting back an invalid IP address or none at all.

You could check this by doing a Dns.Resolve call in your code to see what it gets back.  It might also be easier to try accessing the service by IP address directly instead of using the machine name, thereby bypassing DNS altogether.

Comment: I have tried using both the IP address and my machine name for the web service URL. When I use vxUtil both correctly respond to the ping and GET request to the URL. I'm going to try and see what traffic I can see with Wireshark.